# Replacing first one or two characters of an attribute with conditions on the starting characters

Tags: oracle, replace, substr

```
select distinct a.OriginalAttribute,

CASE WHEN LEFT(a.OriginalAttribute, 1) ='0'  THEN 5||substr(a.OriginalAttribute,2)             

when LEFT(a.OriginalAttribute, 2) ='10' THEN 51||substr(a.OriginalAttribute,3) END AS NEWValue  

 ,b.attributeB, c.attributeC

from tablea a, tableb b, tablec c

where a.KEY = b.key and a.key = c.key;
```

*ERROR :
ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier*

**Error interpretation :**  By the way the Following sql works : this confirms that my "a.OriginalAttribute" is one of the attribut of my table

```
select distinct a.OriginalAttribute,b.attributeB, c.attributeC

from tablea a, tableb b, tablec c

where a.KEY = b.key and a.key = c.key;
```

==> I don't undesrstand why Oracle does not find it once I put it on the left function.

The desired result :

if a.OriginalAttribute starts with " 0 ",   remplace the " 0 " by " 5 "   (example : `004441 -> 504441`)

if a.OriginalAttribute starts with " 10 ",  remplace the " 10 " by " 51 " (exemple : `104441 -> 514441`)

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such function in Oracle.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you for your interation. Have you a proposition so that I can have the desired result in Oracle please (or any link which could help me) thank you a lot.

Comment: link was provided in 1st comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr instead of left.

```
select distinct a.OriginalAttribute,
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(a.OriginalAttribute, 1, 1) ='0'  
     THEN 5||substr(a.OriginalAttribute,2)             
     when SUBSTR(a.OriginalAttribute, 1 ,2) ='10' 
     THEN 51||substr(a.OriginalAttribute,3) END AS NEWValue  
 ,b.attributeB, c.attributeC
from tablea a, tableb b, tablec c
```

where a.KEY = b.key and a.key = c.key;

Comment: hello Paul , Thank you a lot for your help it works. But in one case it's a bit complicated. Once  we inverse the task : if 51% ==> 10% and if 5%  ==> 0%. Here is an example. With this SQL I have not the desired result since both start with 5 :510408  ==>     010408

504320 ==>       004320

Comment: or `CASE WHEN a.originalattribute LIKE '0%' THEN '5'||SUBSTR(a.originalattribute,2) WHEN a.originalattribute LIKE '10%' THEN '51'||SUBSTR(a.originalattribute,3) END`

Comment: @mirette Simple string functions like `SUBSTR` are much more efficient than regular expressions so this will perform better, even if this looks more complicated.

Comment: @MT0 thank you for your answer as Paul's answer and Littlefoot sql; yours is also OK; but KO in this case : if 5% ==> 0% and if 51% ==> 10%. Since both start with "5" it is confusing : here is a result of the SQL with your sql proposition : 510408 ==> 010408 or it has to be : 100408 504320 ==> 004320 : the correct answer 004320

Comment: @mirette It sounds like you just need to reverse the `WHEN` clauses and check for `51` in the first clause and `5` in the second.

Comment: @MT0 This is exactly what I have done. `CASE WHEN a.originalattribute LIKE '5%' THEN '0'||SUBSTR(a.originalattribute,2) WHEN a.originalattribute LIKE '51%' THEN '10'||SUBSTR(a.originalattribute,3) END`. Since there is a bit confuse both the first caracter is 5 and 5 (from 51) it gives me 0 all the cases.

Comment: @mirette No, you haven't reversed it. If you had then you would have: `CASE WHEN a.originalattribute LIKE '51%' THEN '10'||SUBSTR(a.originalattribute,3) WHEN a.originalattribute LIKE '5%' THEN '0'||SUBSTR(a.originalattribute,2)  END`

Comment: @MT0 soory I did not understood I mean I have just changed the content of case. OK I am going to try the reverse. THANK YOU !

Comment: @M01 it works; with just inversing the order of my cases. Can you please explain (I though that the order in the case clause is not important ! And if you want to type your answer so that I can rate it as the solution of my question. Again,thank you for you all who have read me and given me these 3 good answers ;)

Comment: @Paul stearns and Littlefoot : Again thank you for your answers. It works also. I have tried the inversion (case 51% then case 5% propositions as said by MT0). Now I have 3 answers which work all thank you. But if someone of you can tell me more (or give me a link) so that I can understand why order matters in the second case : if 5% ==> 0% and if 51% ==> 10%. (ex 510408 ==> 100408 /  504320 ==> 004320) I'd be happy to receive an explanation. Thank you again. (Am gonna try to pick all the answers as solved my pblm). => Unfortunately only one answer could be typed as solved the pblm.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, see if something like this would help:

```
select distinct 
  a.OriginalAttribute,
  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a.OriginalAttribute, '^0', '5'), '^10', '51') as NEWValue,
  b.attributeB, 
  c.attributeC
from tablea a join tableb b on a.key = b.key
join tablec c on a.key = c.key;
```

because of this:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '004441' from dual union all
  3     select '104441' from dual union all
  4     select '312345' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '^0', '5'), '^10', '51') result
  8  from test;

COL    RESULT
------ --------------------
004441 504441
104441 514441
312345 312345

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. As I said the same interpretation to Paul. It works also thank you a lot. But once we have this case (inversing the task) : if 5% ==> 0% and if 51% ==> 10%. Since both start with "5" it is confusing :  510408   ==>    010408 or it has to be : 100408

504320  ==>    004320 : the correct answer 004320